# Unable to proof print on dark colored paper

Tags: print-production, proofing

I am trying to do a proof print on coloured paper in order to simulate offset printing on the same paper, but my plotter refuses to print. It loads the paper, passes over it with the light diode, probably measuring it and expels it. When I try to print on the same paper, but of a brighter color, it prints the same file, same print job.

- Printer: HP Designjet 130NR
- Paper: Mondi IQ Colour Dark Blue
- Software: Indesign CC
- Colour: Grayscale

Is it normal that a printing machine has troubles with dark coloured paper? 
Why does that happen and is there a way to proof print on this paper?

Comment: It sounds like a problem we had with the offset press at my job. The sensor couldn't see black paper, so we had to paint white stripes on the black paper to make it visible to the sensor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You mean that although I use a plotter for “proof printing” and you an offset printer the problem is the same or that the printer does not recognize the paper with its sensor? That is what I thought, but I wanted a feedback on it. Thanks again! ... And I spend half an hour putting the paper back into the tray ;0)

Comment: Maybe you can find the sensor and apply a white label on the dark paper at that spot. It's not ideal but maybe it could work.

Comment: Since the printhead travels over the paper with the led turned on, I do not know where to place the white label, but I will try your first suggestion and apply a strip of white paint on the first sheet. A TipEX roller should do the job.

Comment: Your suggestion works! When I apply a thin line of white paint to the paper, the printer accepts it and prints. I am now able to proof print on the paper and verify everything. If you would write your suggestion as an answer I would be glad to accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear! I can't write an answer since the question is on hold because it is "off-topic". I don't agree - this is a common problem with a simple solution.

Comment: I don't understand why it is put on hold either. It is a generic question about how to use dark coloured paper. I added my configuration only to add some context. And your suggestion is a typical "hack" you would want from an expert. Maybe those who put it on hold could add some context, edit the question or give feedback. I already tried to render it more generic, let us see. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand why it is put on hold, either, but it's almost certainly not a generic question about how to use dark-coloured paper.

It’s almost certainly a very specific question about how that particular printer - possibly, HP printers in general - handles dark paper. Do you see the difference?

HP support should, and some HP dealers, consultants or support specialists will be able to explain both exactly what’s wrong and exactly how to overcome the problem… but almost certainly, only from specific experience and not from any theory.

Comment: I see, but the same would be true for any question about other tools such as Indesign, Quark Xpress, scissors, etc. The nice thing about design is that it is a practice, when you experiment things become specific.